# Computer reacts toward a normal DVD as a bootable DVD

Tags: windows-xp, boot, dvd

I have a PC running XP with the following specs. When I put some DVD which contains some apps and multimedia files, and restart the machine, in the boot screen (when the name of the motherboard and other hardware are coming up - the black first screen) it reacts toward that DVD like a bootable DVD and writes "Boot from CD/DVD" and will be frozen. That is, in this case, neither it goes to XP OS nor any other keys (like, Enter, ctrl+alt+del, and so on) work.
I don't know what is the problem with the machine and that DVD. 
Is there any idea how to fix this problem please?

Pentium 4 CPU 3 GHz
1 GB RAM
RADEON 9250

Comment: You have to enter BIOS and change the boot order. Press F2 etc on startup

Comment: you mean that I change the boot order to be not from CD/DVD and then (when reinstalling some time) again change it to the state of now?

Comment: yes, or do not leave a dvd/cd in the tray.

Comment: Most likely there is an additional F-Key you can press to get a one-time boot device selection menu. That is more convenient for the usually rare occasion of OS installations. Could be F11 or F12 for example.

Comment: Thank you guys. I could to get rid of that problem but do you know why the boot is sensitive with this DVD? What do you think please?

Comment: There must be an incomplete boot configuration on it. If you copy the files to another DVD and burn it, making sure it is not configured as bootable, then you should be OK.

Comment: one of you could make an answer instead of those valuable comments so that I can to compensation them by answer vote!